# How to update SharePoint 2013 list item in REST Service

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

This is my Rest service to update list item

```
URL:
    https://site/_api/lists/getbytitle('Test')/items(49)

Header 
   X-RequestDigest   :   some unique id from contextinfo post service
   Content-Type      :   application/json;odata=verbose 
   X-HTTP-Method     :   MERGE  
   IF-MATCH          :   49

Body 
   {"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.TestListItem"},"Title":"Title all1","Option1":"Updated 2"}
```

When I run this URL in post man I get an error:

> The request ETag value '__metadata.etag' does not match the object's
>   ETag value '\"8\"'

But If I change `IF-MATCH` value in header as *, It's updating properly. Why I am getting an error if use etag ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### About eTag

> When updating or deleting items within SharePoint lists via REST you
>   must specify the Entity Tag (eTag) value that was returned with the
>   item during the initial query. This enables SharePoint to determine if
>   the item has changed since it was requested. Alternatively you can
>   tell SharePoint to perform the operation regardless by specifying * as
>   the eTag value. For example:
>
> - `If-Match`: item.__metadata.etag can be used to specify the actual    eTag value (‘item’ is the object returned from SharePoint containing
>     the list item in JSON format).
> - `If-Match`: `*` can be used to match any eTag value resulting in the    operation being performed regardless of the actual value.