# Update List Item in Sharepoint using old Sharepoint-API in Postman

Tags: list, hyperlink, item, update, postman

I already asked a question here: [enter link description here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/288142/get-the-x-requestdigest-cookie-from-sharepoint-in-postman)
I wanted to retrieve the x-requestdigest from sharepoint to make list-operations just using postman.
The provided solution worked great to do some GET-Commands! I get my list data in XML-format.

Now i'm facing a problem when trying to update a list item in postman.
What i do: i use the same endpoint like in the get-request to update the listitem, so:
[https://mytenantname.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('mylist')/items(id)](https://mytenantname.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle(%27mylist%27)/items(id))
or
[https://mytenantname.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/lists(guid'my_guid')/items(id)](https://mytenantname.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/lists(guid%27my_guid%27)/items(id))

The body content of my request i took from the following link:
[how-do-i-update-a-hyperlink-field-using-the-rest-api](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88540/how-do-i-update-a-hyperlink-field-using-the-rest-api)

```
    {
    '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.mylistListItem' },
    'myhyperlinkcolumn': 
            {
                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.FieldUrlValue' },
                'Description': 'some_description',
                'Url': 'https://anyurl.com'
            }
    }
```

I always get a Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException. The Errormessage always says that the field __metadata does not exist in the functions GetByID or GetByName. Even when i try to update just another normal string-field, i get the same errormessage including the name of the concerning fieldname. I also tried to send my request with the xml i retrieved from the get-command containing the new update values, but this seems not to be the right way.

Does anyone have an idea what i do wrong?
None of the solutions i found on StackExchange worked for me, so it may be possible that updates also don't seem to be straight forward when not using the .NET-framework?
Thanks for a reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the solution on [how-to-update-sharepoint-list-items](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/178739/how-to-update-sharepoint-2013-list-item-in-rest-service)

I fixed the problem by adding two more header entries:
IF-MATCH = * and
X-HTTP-Method = MERGE

Now the updates are working fine!